# Change blog description using Tumblr API

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

Is there a possible way to change my Tumblr Blog's description using the Tumblr API?  I know I can get the description but can I change it?  I want to set up a 'description queue' so it will change my description daily.

Comment: No. User details (avatar, blogname, description, etc) are read only: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog-info

Comment: @mikedidthis oh ok, thanks.  and I read through that but I didn't see anything saying read only, I saw you can read it but never read only, maybe I missed it.

Comment: If the `HTTP Method` is `GET` with no `POST` method, consider it read only. Generally anything other that what a user would do on the Dashboard (Post, Like, Reblog, Follow, etc) you can't do via the API sadly.

Comment: @mikedidthis ok, I'm new at APIs :P thanks though

Comment: @mikedidthis also you should write that as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: You write it as an answer :D Nice badge for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No I cannot, since the `HTTP Method` is `GET` and has no `POST` it makes the description Read-Only.